# how to add a letter to a reverse string using a for loop in python

Tags: python

i am beginner at python coding. I want my output to be:
example 1:

```
Word: hello #hello is the input
o
ol
oll
olle
olleh
```

example 2:

```
Word: nice # nice is the input
e
ec
eci
ecin
```

basically, it codes backwards but it shows each letter being added.
My codes till now are:

```
text = input("Words: ")
reserved_text = text[::-1]
print(reserved_text)
-------------output----
Words: Nice
eciN
```

I don't know how to use the for loop to get the steps that comes before the whole reversed word.

Comment: did you try to use the `for` loop at all?

Comment: Hint: use a for loop, and print the reversed text until[:1], then until [:2] and so forth

Comment: @EdChum i did try, but it went too confusing.

Comment: You need to show your full code.

Comment: If you tried, you should post your attempt, and someone might help you with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a school example. But I assume you're not here trying to easy get the solution of a rated exercise ;)

That being said : you may want to use a for loop.

```
text = input("Words: ")
for i in range(1,len(text)+1):
  print(text[::-1][:i:])
```

Answer (score 1):

As strings in python are innmutables you have to use an auxiliary string to get the output you want. Also you must use "reversed"

```
s = input ("Words: ")

s_rev = ""

for n in reversed(s):
    s_rev = s_rev + n
    print s_rev
```